# Replace file path by it's content with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need to translate;

```
\verbatiminput{code.R}
```

into

```
\begin{verbatim}
#### Hello world ####
print ("hello world")
#####################
\end{verbatim}
```

That is putting the content of the file `code.R` instead of the path.

One solution is;

```
perl -pe 's{\\verbatiminput\{(.*?)\}}{local$/;open F,"<$1";"\\begin{verbatim}".<F>}ge'
```

1. How to add the `\end{verbatim}` ?
2. Any better regex ?

Comment: File path by the file's contents? What results do you expect and why do you want it that way? Clarifying your question a bit more will make answering easier for us :)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but I'd rewrite like this (actually I might do it as script not a one liner)

- # instead of { is clearer
- q() instead of "" means less interpolation
- whitespace in `local $/`
- more () to make intention clearer
- I'm pretty sure that  in a join will be in array context and so will read the whole file.  Whereas  in scalar context will read one line

`perl -pe 's#\\verbatiminput{(.*?)}#local $/;open(F,"<$1");join(q(),q(\begin{verbatim}"),<F>,q(\end{verbatim})#ge'`

Answer (score 2):

If your `sed` supports the `e` modifier, you can do the following:

```
$ cat testdata
foo
\verbatiminput{file1}
bar
\verbatiminput{file2}
quux

$ sed -e 's#\\verbatiminput{\([^}]*\)}#echo "\\begin{verbatim}";cat "\1";echo "\\end{verbatim}"#ge' testdata
foo
\begin{verbatim}
this
is
file1

\end{verbatim}
bar
\begin{verbatim}
this
is
file2

\end{verbatim}
quux
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this input:

```
$ cat input
some line 1
some line 2
\verbatiminput{code.R}
some line 3
\verbatiminput{code1.R}

$ cat code.R 
#### Hello world ####
print ("hello world")
#####################

$ cat code1.R 
#### Goodby world ####
print ("goodby world")
#####################
```

and the following bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='^\verbatiminput\{(.*)\}$'

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    then 
        file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo \\begin{verbatim}
        cat $file
        echo \\end{verbatim}
    else
        echo $line
    fi
done < input
```

this will give the following output:

```
some line 1
some line 2
\begin{verbatim}
#### Hello world ####
print ("hello world")
#####################
\end{verbatim}
some line 3
\begin{verbatim}
#### Goodby world ####
print ("goodby world")
#####################
\end{verbatim}
```

This uses `=~` which is Bash's regex match operator. The results of the match are saved to an array called `$BASH_REMATCH`. The first capture group is stored in index 1, the second (if any) in index 2, etc. Index zero is the full match.

Comment: Based on how I understand the question I'm pretty sure the OP does not have/want their TeX markup in the external files, so this is not exactly the solution being asked for, but I like the use of `BASH_REMATCH` since this is a feature that many don't know about...maybe you can adapt your answer to make it add the markup as part of the script.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Perhaps it's sleep deprivation (3 girls @ home who refuses to sleep) but didn't we sort of produce the same output?

Comment: Hehe, enjoy. I meant that your code requires `\begin{verbatim}` / `\end{verbatim}` to be part of the files in question, whereas I think what Ben wants/needs is that the script itself takes care of adding this markup and that the external files be "plain" and don't contain them (just an assumption, though) - the ouput is the same, but the input is not. But my assumption might be wrong :-)

Comment: Actually, I need the \begin{verbatim}. Thanks for the script.